# Не могу понять принципа работы цикла for в JS

Tags: javascript, for

Суть: надо добавить элемент trash ко всем элементам списка.

```
    const trash = document.createElement('i');
    trash.className = 'far fa-trash-alt';


    for (const file of curFiles) {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        const image = document.createElement('img');



        para.textContent = 'Имя файла: ' + file.name + ', Размер файла: ' + corectSize(file.size);

        if (validFileType(file)) {
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        } else {
            image.src = 'img/file.png';
        };

        listItem.append(image);
        listItem.append(para);
        listItem.append(trash);
        list.append(listItem);
    };
```

Если я создаю переменную до цикла, то добавляется только к последнему элементу.

А если делаю так:

```
        for (const file of curFiles) {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        const para = document.createElement('p');
        const image = document.createElement('img');

        const trash = document.createElement('i');
        trash.className = 'far fa-trash-alt';

        para.textContent = 'Имя файла: ' + file.name + ', Размер файла: ' + corectSize(file.size);

        if (validFileType(file)) {
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        } else {
            image.src = 'img/file.png';
        };

        listItem.append(image);
        listItem.append(para);
        listItem.append(trash);
        list.append(listItem);
    };
```

То добавляется ко всем элементам. Проблема решена.... Но почему так происходит??? Ведь в обоих случаях элемент доступен для цикла в каждой итерации... Простите заранее , за может быть глупый вопрос. Я только изучаю JS.

Comment: Потому что в первом варианте ты создал один элемент и его в каждой итерации добавляешь к следующему чему-то там. То есть переменная хранит ссылку на один объект в памяти. Больше таких нет. И в каждой итерации этот элемент меняет своё положение и свойства. А во втором варианте сделано всё верно. Потому что нам надо к каждому элементу добавить НОВЫЙ элемент. То есть в каждой итерации создаётся новый элемент в памяти, со своими свойствами, а не один единственный, который в каждой итерации просто куда-то гоняем и изменяем его. Вот. надеюсь понятно описал :)

Comment: Да всё понятно спасибо! Я наивно полагал, что будет создаваться объект, при каждом вызове переменной.